# Check column for unique value

Tags: mysql, sql

My table:

```
id attribute
1  2
1  2
2  3
2  4
5  1
5  1
6  3
6  3
6  5
```

Now I want only to output those `id` with `attribute`, if the attribute is the same for each `id`.

In this sample table, the output would be

```
id attribute
1  2
5  1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use this approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, attribute 
FROM test t1 
WHERE (SELECT count(DISTINCT attribute) 
       FROM test t2 
       WHERE t2.id = t1.id) = 1
```

A better approach could be:

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT t1.id, t1.attribute
FROM
   test t1,
   (
      SELECT
         id,
         count(DISTINCT attribute) COUNT
      FROM
         test
      GROUP BY
         id
      HAVING
         COUNT = 1
   ) t2
WHERE
   t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: This method is very inefficient, because it will run that inner query for every row in test. This will start to impact performance quite quickly as the table grows.

Comment: @Braiba: You are right. The second approach could reduce the complexity.

Comment: The inner query is functionally the same as ypercube's first one; I don't see what the outer query adds here, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT id, MIN(attribute) AS attribute 
FROM test  
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attribute) = 1 ;
```

or:

```
SELECT id, MIN(attribute) AS attribute
FROM test 
GROUP BY id
HAVING MIN(attribute) = MAX(attribute) ;
```

I would expect the last version to be quite efficient with an index on `(id, attribute)`

Comment: +1 for the most efficient way of doing this. The MIN=MAX thing is really clever; I'll be remembering that trick for the future.

Comment: I really like this answer as well. What is the etiquette on SO? First come first serve or best answer?

Comment: @Terry Uhlang Best answer makes the most sense to me since it will be the first one other users with the same problem will see when they search for this question.

Comment: @TerryUhlang: The answer that you used or the one that helped you most or the one that you think is best. The choice is yours: [Which answer do I accept if I have multiple correct answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers)

Comment: Surely if `MIN(attribute) = MAX(attribute)` it would be safe to simply `SELECT id, attribute`? Could there be some performance advantage to reusing `MIN()` in this instance?

Comment: @AirThomas, it might be safe but it would not be a valid query. And even if `MIN(attribute)=MAX(attribute)` there still might be rows where the `attribute` is `NULL`. So, it is not safe either.

Comment: Actually, you can select columns not included in the `GROUP BY` statement in MySQL. But your point about `NULL` values is taken.

Comment: Yes, you can. Depending on what settings you have though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd use the following approach instead:

```
     SELECT DISTINCT ta.id, ta.attribute
       FROM test ta
  LEFT JOIN test tb
         ON ta.id = tb.id AND ta.attribute <> tb.attribute
      WHERE tb.id IS NULL;
```

... as I usually tend to at least trying to replace nested queries with joined tables. Of course, if your table is small, it won't matter much.

Comment: Nested queries are fine so long as you join onto them, rather than putting them in a SELECT/WHERE/ON clause. Joining a table onto itself like this isn't much better though; the processing time will still increase exponentially as the table grows.